# ASP.NET MVC file downloading as plain text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to download a simple txt file to client pc but in request response only plain text is showing and file is not getting downloaded. Here is my code

```
   public virtual FileContentResult generateCKRM(string Code,string Name)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        CHOO.TOSSRepository.TOSSRepository tr = new CHOO.TOSSRepository.TOSSRepository();
        dt = tr.GetDetails(Code, Name);
            return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output), "text/plain", "CKRM_" + Code+ "_" + Name+ ".txt");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have also tried return type ActionResult with no results.
Here is my ajax Calling,

```
    function GenerateFile() {
    $('body').loader('show');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Portal/generateCKRM',
        data: {
            'Code': $('#txtCode').val(), 'Name': $('#txtName').val()
        },
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           // window.location = 'file=' + data;
            $('body').loader('hide');
        },
        error: function () { alert('Server Error! Please try again later.'); $('body').loader('hide'); }
    });
}
```

Every thing is fine and i can see the response in browser but no file is being downloaded.
[Response Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5KY2.png)

Response Header Values are as below

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CKRM_Arew_8712.txt
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1387
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:50:13 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Update:
I can download the file in web form application using

```
            StringWriter oStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            oStringWriter.WriteLine(output);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "CKRM_"+code.Text+"_"+Name.Text+".edi");
            Response.Clear();

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream))
            {
                writer.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
            }
            Response.End();
```

Comment: "only plain text is showing and file is not getting downloaded"...this is because your browser has the ability to view text files. It would be the same for an image file or HTML file or anything else it can display. So the file technically _is_ downloaded (because it can't be displayed on the user's machine unless it's been fetched from the server), it's just in a temporary location and shown by the browser. The user can still save it using File -> Save As

Comment: Also the fact you're trying to do this via ajax won't be helping. Files cannot be downloaded via ajax - the data just ends up in a JavaScript variable in the browser, and never on the user's disk. Also it's hard to see, from your code, how you would be seeing any text at all from the ajax request, since in your "success" callback you don't actually do anything with the response. Are you certain the ajax is actually running, and you're not simply doing a postback or navigating to this URL directly instead?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your reply, I got your point but this piece of code is also not working for .EDI format, I can download the same file in web form application using response header, Please see my updated question.
Also ajax is working fine as i am getting the response in browser. I am not doing anything in success callback because i just want the controller to download file and if success i will simply show a message to user in success callback.

Comment: "Also ajax is working fine as i am getting the response in browser"...yes but as I just mentioned, AJAX cannot be used to download the file _to the user's disk_. It will just always end up in a variable in your script. You need to make a regular HTTP request to that URL in order to initiate a proper download.

Comment: @ADyson
Thank you very much for showing me the right way, I just used a javascript function in my success callback to download the string as file.

Comment: " I just used a javascript function in my success callback to download the string as file." I still would recommend just making a direct HTTP request (e.g. using window.open or window.location, or by getting the user to click a hyperlink (depending how you trigger the download, I don't know). The AJAX part is redundant, you can simplify your code by getting rid of all that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just created a controller method to download file and on success callback triggered that by window.location.href hence got rid of all that javascript.

Comment: "on success callback"...sounds like you're still using AJAX though? Do you mean it's an AJAX call to some other method, and then after that method returns you then trigger the download? That would be fine. But if it's an AJAX call to '/Portal/generateCKRM' followed by a window.location.href going to '/Portal/generateCKRM' then you're just making the same request twice for no reason, and you can ditch that ajax call.

Comment: of course I am not using generateCKRM again, I moved the download part to another method just to download file.

Comment: Ok great. Just thought I would clarify to be 100% certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to prevent the navigator to show the file use `application/octet-stream` :

```
return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output), "application/octet-stream", "CKRM_" + Code+ "_" + Name+ ".txt");
```

and to download file via ajax :

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Portal/generateCKRM',
        data: {
            'Code': $('#txtCode').val(), 'Name': $('#txtName').val()
        },
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'file.txt';
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

            $('body').loader('hide');
        },
        error: function () { alert('Server Error! Please try again later.'); $('body').loader('hide'); }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Mustapha, It gave me an idea.

Comment: Why the need for all this code and creating fake hyperlink objects, when a simple `window.open` command containing the URL would do the job just the same?